# JPA/Hibernate cascading persist doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem cascading the persist operation to children.

I have a *parent* and a *child* class. When I save the parent with one child with a Spring-Data Repository the values of the child are all null or 0.

If I add CascadeType.ALL to the OneToMany-Annotation I get this error:
**"multiple representations of the same entity are being merged"**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestParent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<TestChild> children;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestChild {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private int value;

    @ManyToOne
    private TestParent parent;
}
```

Here is the code to test if saving the objects work:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void test123(){
    TestParent parent = new TestParent();
    parent = testRepo.save(parent);

    TestChild child1 = new TestChild();
    child1.setValue(3);
    child1.setParent(parent);
    parent.setChildren(new ArrayList<>());
    parent.getChildren().add(child1);

    parent = testRepo.save(parent);

    assertThat(parent.getChildren().size()).isNotZero();
    assertThat(parent.getChildren().get(0).getValue()).isEqualTo(3);
}
```

So my approach is to fix cascading the Persist without adding the cascadeType Merge. Any hints what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Then don't save the parent. The second save is an update and thus a merge. A persist is only valid for new non-persistent instances. Next to that you are destroying the managed collection by doing a `new ArrayList()` before adding the child. imho your code is flawed in multiple ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [Hibernate User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) is a great resource if you want to learn something about mapping entities to DB.

I checked your example and it works on my machine (TM) with following repo declaration:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<HibernateProxyDemoApplication.TestParent, Long> {  }
```

And spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories // just to make sure
public class HibernateProxyDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HibernateProxyDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
...
}
```

and `pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I can only suggest to you to first remove Lombok annotations (@Getter/@Setter) and to write getters/setters manually, then to look what may be wrong with your program.

PS. It also works with cascade ALL

Comment: I also created a new SpringBootApplication with spring-boot 1.5.5 now. (Before i was using 1.4.4). But it doesn't work. 

My gradle dependencies are: spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, mysql-connector-java, spring-boot-starter-test

Comment: Thanks for the tips. 
Upgrade to spring-boot 1.5.5 and using Cascade ALL worked finally. With the new spring version I don't get the error "multiple representations of the same entity are being merged" anymore